# How to Calculate the Element Addresses of an N-Dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, operators

From what I understand, blocks of allocated memory is continuous, so addresses in an array are sequential in multiples of the size of the array data (int = 4 on some systems, etc.)

I've also seen that for an array A and index i, `A[i] == *(A+i)` in C.

A 2D array is like an array of arrays, so I wanted to know how to determine the expression for an N-dimensional array if I was crazy enough not to use the `[]` operator.

If the array was created with pointers, wouldn't it be necessary to know the length of the level?

Comment: When you say "2D array", do you mean an array of arrays like `int array[X][Y]`? An array of pointers, like `int *array[X]`? A pointer to an array, like `int (*array)[X]`? Or a pointer to pointer, like `int **array`? While all of those can be accessed with simple indexing, their layout in memory is different, and so you need different expressions for each if you don't want to use array indexing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I mean arrays like int array[x][y], int array[x][y][z], int array[][]...[]. 
But now I think about it, I'm curious about all since I didn't know their layout is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
int array2d[X][Y];
```

the two expressions are equivalent:

```
array[1][2];
*((int *)array + 1*Y + 2);
```

For

```
int array3d[X][Y][Z]
```

the two expressions are equivalent:

```
array[1][2][3];
*((int *)arr + 1*Y*Z + 2*Z + 3);
```

So, for

```
int arraynd[X][Y][Z]..[N]
```

the two expression are equivalent:

```
arraynd[1][2][3]...[n];
((int *)array + 1*X*Y*Z*...*N + 2*Y*Z*...*N + 3*Z*...*N + ... + n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you declare `int a[m][n];`  If you reference `a[i][j]`, it is equivalent to `(a[i])[j]` which, as you noted, is equivalent to `(*(a+i))[j]`, which is equivalent to `*((*(a+i))+j)`.  In terms of bytes, the integer is scaled by the size of the object pointed to, so `i` is scaled by the size of `a[0]`, or `*a`, which is the size of the sub-array, which is `sizeof(int) * n`.  The dereference of the result, via the `*` operator, is essentially a type cast, converting it from a pointer to the sub-array, type `int (*)[n]`, to a pointer to an element of the sub-array, type `int *`.  Then, when adding `j`, it is scaled by `sizeof(int)`.  The outer dereference, via the `*` operator, actually dereferences the pointer, either reading the value or modifying it, depending on the context.

Edit:  Here's a simple demonstration program you can try.  It illustrates what I explained:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int     a[5][10];

    printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof(int[5][10]), sizeof(int[10]), sizeof(int));
    printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0][0]));
    printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(*a), sizeof(**a));

    void   *p1 = a;
    void   *p2 = a + 1;
    void   *p3 = *(a + 1) + 3;

    printf("%d %d\n", (int) (p2 - p1), (int) (p3 - p2));
    printf("%d %d\n", 1 * (sizeof(int) * 10), 3 * sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```